# Struggling with many to many field

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to create a new product.
Here is my model :

```
class Product(models.Model) :
    door = models.ForeignKey(Door, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    options = models.ManyToManyField(Option)
```

Here is my views :

```
def new_product(request, door_id) :
    door = get_object_or_404(Door, id=door_id)
    checked = request.POST.getlist('checks[]')
    c_checked = []
    for check in checked :
        new_check = get_object_or_404(Option, name=check)
        c_checked.append(new_check)
    product = Product.objects.create(
        door = door,
        options = c_checked,
        )
    product.save()
    return render(request, "confirmation.html")
```

Unfortunately, when I run the server, I get an error saying :

> Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is
>   prohibited.  Use options.set() instead

Please help me if you have the answer.

.

Comment: There is no reason to call `save` just after `create`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/), you should use `add`. `create` method represents one insert in a database but you want to insert multiple records.

```
def new_product(request, door_id) :
    door = get_object_or_404(Door, id=door_id)
    checked = request.POST.getlist('checks[]')
    c_checked = []
    for check in checked :
        new_check = get_object_or_404(Option, name=check)
        c_checked.append(new_check)
    product = Product.objects.create(door=door)
    product.options.add(*c_checked)
    return render(request, "confirmation.html")
```

Comment: Thank you very much